Failed to instantiate [...SparkSession]: Factory method 'sparkSession'-Can't invoke "java.util.Map.get(Object)" because "currentValues" is null
Getting this error while trying out Apache Spark 4.0.0-preview1 with Java (v17) Springboot (v3.2.5) application. A sample SparkConfig where I am getting the above error while creating 'javaSparkContext'.
@Configuration
public class SparkConfig {

    @Value("${spark.app.name}")
    private String appName;

    @Value("${spark.master}")
    private String masterUri;

    @Bean
    public SparkConf sparkConf() throws IOException {
        var conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName(appName)
                .setMaster(masterUri);
        return conf;
    }

    @Bean
    public SparkSession sparkSession(JavaSparkContext sparkContext) {
        return SparkSession.builder()
                .sparkContext(sparkContext.sc())
                .config(sparkContext.getConf())
                .getOrCreate();
    }

    @Bean
    public JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext(SparkConf sparkConf) {
        return new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    }
}

Could someone suggest a solution for the issue!
Please find below the stack trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sparkSession' defined in class path resource [com/sparktest/batchtest/config/SparkConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sparkSession' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'javaSparkContext' defined in class path resource [com/sparktest/batchtest/config/SparkConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext]: Factory method 'javaSparkContext' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.get(Object)" because "currentValues" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:542) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at com.sparktest.batchtest.main(batchtest.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'javaSparkContext' defined in class path resource [com/sparktest/batchtest/config/SparkConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext]: Factory method 'javaSparkContext' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.get(Object)" because "currentValues" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext]: Factory method 'javaSparkContext' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.get(Object)" because "currentValues" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.get(Object)" because "currentValues" is null
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.CloseableThreadContext$Instance.putAll(CloseableThreadContext.java:170) ~[log4j-api-2.21.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.CloseableThreadContext.putAll(CloseableThreadContext.java:100) ~[log4j-api-2.21.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.withLogContext(Logging.scala:166) ~[spark-common-utils_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.withLogContext$(Logging.scala:165) ~[spark-common-utils_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withLogContext(SparkContext.scala:85) ~[spark-core_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.logInfo(Logging.scala:182) ~[spark-common-utils_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.logInfo$(Logging.scala:179) ~[spark-common-utils_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.logInfo(SparkContext.scala:85) ~[spark-core_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:202) ~[spark-core_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:59) ~[spark-core_2.13-4.0.0-preview1.jar:4.0.0-preview1]
    at com.sparktest.jobengine.config.SparkConfig.javaSparkContext(SparkConfig.java:81) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sparktest.jobengine.config.SparkConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$javaSparkContext$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sparktest.jobengine.config.SparkConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at com.sparktest.jobengine.config.SparkConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.javaSparkContext(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    ... 34 common frames omitted

This error is coming when Spark Session is being created. Tried even without a config class and getting the same error!

In order for others to help please provide the stack trace showing where that error is coming from.  Also do you have the same issue if you are using 3.5 (i.e. is it actually Spark 4 relevant)?

Hi Chris,  updated the above with stack trace. We are trying to migrate our existing solution to Java 17 and Spring-boot v3.2  and trying out Spark-4.0.0 preview. We cannot use Spark 3.5 with Spring-boot as it isn't working because of 'javax' (which Spark 3.5 is still using) is renamed to 'jakarta'.

This is log4j/slf4j versions clash problem:
Managed to fix similiar issue by excluding log4/slf4j from spark/hadoop:
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-preview1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-preview1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

also removed/excluded logback/log4j-to-slf4j everywhere I find it:
<!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

and added log4j by spring dependency:
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

